# Simplified Spring Bookmark tutorial fails to instantiate my repository bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've tried to make an ultra-simplified version of the [Spring Bookmark tutorial](http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/) (using gradle rather than maven). My code can be found here: https://github.com/JetForMe/spring-hoa/tree/master/src/main/java/com/latencyzero/hoa

Among the changes I made was to call "User" what the tutorial calls "Account," and minor stylistic changes that I don't *think* are causing the problem, but they might be, if it's a name-matching issue (but I think Spring is smart enough to look for types).

In any case, my `UserRepository` class is not getting instantiated, and therefore not auto-wiring up to the rest of my classes. Poring over the tutorial, I don't see any special effort to instantiate the repositories.

The log shows something that might be a red herring: "Spring Data MongoDB - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.latencyzero.hoa.UserRepository."

Here's the full log:

```
$ gradle bootRun
:compileJava
:processResources
:classes
:findMainClass
:bootRun
2016-10-25 02:53:00.108  INFO 99423 --- [  restartedMain] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@3f1dba7: startup date [Tue Oct 25 02:53:00 PDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-10-25 02:53:00.376  INFO 99423 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8758e0b1] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.1.RELEASE)

2016-10-25 02:53:00.593  INFO 99423 --- [  restartedMain] com.latencyzero.hoa.Application          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-10-25 02:53:00.605  INFO 99423 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@ae0374c: startup date [Tue Oct 25 02:53:00 PDT 2016]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@3f1dba7
2016-10-25 02:53:01.873  INFO 99423 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'ignoredPathsWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration; factoryMethodName=ignoredPathsWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration; factoryMethodName=ignoredPathsWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class]]
2016-10-25 02:53:02.047  INFO 99423 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2016-10-25 02:53:02.069  INFO 99423 --- [  restartedMain] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data MongoDB - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.latencyzero.hoa.UserRepository.
2016-10-25 02:53:02.150  WARN 99423 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor  : Cannot enhance @Configuration bean definition 'refreshScope' since its singleton instance has been created too early. The typical cause is a non-static @Bean method with a BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor return type: Consider declaring such methods as 'static'.
2016-10-25 02:53:02.367  INFO 99423 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=ca9236f5-9f66-359b-bc2d-0d19b66d24be
2016-10-25 02:53:02.485  INFO 99423 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6b3eddb4] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-10-25 02:53:02.530  INFO 99423 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8758e0b1] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-10-25 02:53:02.980  INFO 99423 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-10-25 02:53:02.991  INFO 99423 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-10-25 02:53:02.992  INFO 99423 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.5
2016-10-25 02:53:03.076  INFO 99423 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-10-25 02:53:03.076  INFO 99423 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2471 ms
2016-10-25 02:53:03.414  INFO 99423 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'metricsFilter' to: [/*]
2016-10-25 02:53:03.414  INFO 99423 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-10-25 02:53:03.414  INFO 99423 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-10-25 02:53:03.415  INFO 99423 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2016-10-25 02:53:03.415  INFO 99423 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2016-10-25 02:53:03.416  INFO 99423 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2016-10-25 02:53:03.417  INFO 99423 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'webRequestLoggingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-10-25 02:53:03.417  INFO 99423 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'applicationContextIdFilter' to: [/*]
2016-10-25 02:53:03.417  INFO 99423 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-10-25 02:53:03.457  WARN 99423 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController' defined in file [/Users/rmann/Projects/HOA/spring-hoa/build/classes/main/com/latencyzero/hoa/UserController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean found for dependency [com.latencyzero.hoa.UserRepository]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
2016-10-25 02:53:03.460  INFO 99423 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2016-10-25 02:53:03.472  WARN 99423 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Error handling failed (Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor]: Factory method 'transactionAdvisor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException)
2016-10-25 02:53:03.641 ERROR 99423 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.latencyzero.hoa.UserController required a bean of type 'com.latencyzero.hoa.UserRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.latencyzero.hoa.UserRepository' in your configuration.


BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 11.941 secs
```

Any idea what I overlooked? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it turns out I was missing some dependencies. I added `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`, and `h2`. Now I'm getting a different error, but I'll post a new question about that.